# Pandas - Find longest stretch without Nan values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe "df", a sample of which is below:

```
   time  x
0  1     1
1  2     Nan 
2  3     3
3  4     Nan
4  5     8
5  6     7
6  7     5
7  8     Nan
```

The real frame is much bigger. I am trying to find the longest stretch of non NaN values in the "x" series, and print out the starting and ending index for this frame. Is this possible?

Thank You

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach with NumPy tools -

```
a = df.x.values  # Extract out relevant column from dataframe as array
m = np.concatenate(( [True], np.isnan(a), [True] ))  # Mask
ss = np.flatnonzero(m[1:] != m[:-1]).reshape(-1,2)   # Start-stop limits
start,stop = ss[(ss[:,1] - ss[:,0]).argmax()]  # Get max interval, interval limits
```

Sample run -

```
In [474]: a
Out[474]: 
array([  1.,  nan,   3.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   8.,   7.,   5.,   2.,
         5.,  nan,  nan])

In [475]: start, stop
Out[475]: (7, 12)
```

The intervals are set such that the difference between each start and stop would give us the length of each interval. So, by `ending index` if you meant to get the last index of non-zero element, we need to subtract one from `stop`.

Comment: Very nice solution!

Comment: @JeffSaltfist I am expecting a lot on performance with this. So, hopefully on your large datasets, this would make sense!

Comment: @Divakar, yes, I will be running this on 111 columns with over a million rows each, so the performance aspect is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, this is a few slices less than mine.  Great answer Divakar!

Comment: Wow, just ran it...really powerful. Thanks again, this snippet will be going on my list of great snippets.

Comment: can anyone tell me  what does
m = np.concatenate(( [True], np.isnan(a), [True] ))
means? why put [True] for input array param?

Comment: @ChiaYi `np.concatenate` accepts arrays or lists as inputs for concatenation, hence that one.

Comment: @Divakar thanks for the prompt reply but why concatenate True and isnan values in a and True?

Comment: @ChiaYi That gives us a concatenated mask that has True values at group boundaries (groups decided by the occurrences of NaNs). That's needed in the next step to get Start-stop limits.

Comment: For anyone who wants to find groupings of NaN values, you can do so by concatenating False values instead of True values while constructing the array m

Comment: If there are no valid sequences, one can check for the length of `ss` and return 0 before the `argmax` line.

Answer (score 6):

***pandas***

```
f = dict(
    Start=pd.Series.first_valid_index,
    Stop=pd.Series.last_valid_index,
    Stretch='count'
)

agged = df.x.groupby(df.x.isnull().cumsum()).agg(f)
agged.loc[agged.Stretch.idxmax(), ['Start', 'Stop']].values

array([ 4.,  6.])
```

***numpy***

```
def pir(x):
    # pad with np.nan
    x = np.append(np.nan, np.append(x, np.nan))
    # find where null
    w = np.where(np.isnan(x))[0]
    # diff to find length of stretch
    # argmax to find where largest stretch
    a = np.diff(w).argmax()
    # return original positions of boundary nulls
    return w[[a, a + 1]] + np.array([0, -2])
```

***demo***

```
pir(df.x.values)

array([4, 6])
```

---

```
a = np.array([1, np.nan, 3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 8, 7, 5, 2, 5, np.nan, np.nan])
pir(a)

array([ 7, 11])
```

Answer (score 4):

So you can get the index values of the `NaN`'s in the following way:

```
import numpy as np

index = df['x'].index[df['x'].apply(np.isnan)]
df_index = df.index.values.tolist()
[df_index.index(indexValue) for indexValue in index]

>>> [0, 1, 3, 7]
```

Then one solution would be to see the largest difference between subsequent index values and that would give you the longest stretch of non `NaN` values.

Comment: Your 3 lines could just be replaced with something simpler like `df.index[pd.isnull(df['x'])].tolist()`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a faster way would be the following (given that you say you have a long dataframe, speed matters):

```
In [19]: df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],'x':[1,np.NAN,3,np.NAN,8,7,5,np.NAN]})

In [20]: index = df['x'].isnull()

In [21]: df[index].index.values
Out[21]: array([1, 3, 7])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use [`scipy.ndimage.measurements.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html). It will perform a segmentation of your non null index into valid group and label them differently. You can then group your dataframe using the labels and take the biggest group.

**Set-up**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import label
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],'x':[1,np.NAN,3,np.NAN,8,7,5,np.NAN]})
```

**Retrieving longest stretch without nan**

```
valid_rows = ~df.isnull().any(axis=1)
label, num_feature = label(valid_rows)
label_of_biggest_group =  valid_rows.groupby(label).count().drop(0).argmax()
print df.loc[label == label_of_biggest_group]
```

**Result**

```
   time    x
4     5  8.0
5     6  7.0
6     7  5.0
```

**Note**

The label 0 contains background data in our case the `nan` values and it has to be dropped in case of your number of nan is greater or equal to the size of yout biggest group. `num_feature` is your number of homogeneous stretches without `nan`.