# Python - Finding longest continuous run in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which has the following variables:  week, product code, constraint flag (0 or 1 indicating whether the product supply was constrained).

```
Week    Product_Code    Constraint_Flag
1           A                1
1           B                0
2           A                0
2           B                1
3           A                0
3           B                0
4           A                0
4           B                0
5           A                1
5           B                0
```

I want to find the longest time period that the supply was unconstrained for i.e. the longest string of 0s for each product code.  So for product A I would want to know that the longest string started in week 3 and lasted for 2 weeks, and for product B the longest string started in week 3 and lasted for 3 weeks.

How can I do this?

Comment: Look into groupby

Comment: Aside from that, SO is not a free coding service. Try something first, even if it's only research, and ask when you run into a specific problem with your code.

Comment: @MadPhysicist:  Thanks for the reply.  I've used groupby before and understand that I can group by the product.  However, I need to build some logic in where it is treating it as a sequence of 0s rather than just a count.

Comment: Right, and when you've done that, you'll have either answered your own question of come up with something on topic for this site.

Comment: can you please post expected output. That is more easier to understand.

Comment: You can try to run through your df row by row and check if the value of Constraint_Flag is zero or one. If it is zero, save this in a variable like zero==True and add the row to a second dataframe. If you encounter the situtation that a zero is followed by a one, do nothing instead of setting a indicator variable like Ones==True. If you next face a zero, store the rows in a second df and compare the length of this with the length of the first. Clean the df with the smallest length. Run this for all rows and do the saving and comparing steps and you should get the df with longest 0 path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41494706/2901002) for find longest only 0 period and then filter with aggregate first and last:

```
m  = np.concatenate(( [True], df['Constraint_Flag'] != 0, [True] ))
ss = np.flatnonzero(m[1:] != m[:-1]).reshape(-1,2)
s, e = ss[(ss[:,1] - ss[:,0]).argmax()]
pos = df.columns.get_loc('Week')
print (s,e)
4 8

print (df.iloc[s:e])
   Week Product_Code  Constraint_Flag
4     3            A                0
5     3            B                0
6     4            A                0
7     4            B                0

df = df.iloc[s:e].groupby('Product_Code')['Week'].agg(['first','last'])
print (df)
              first  last
Product_Code             
A                 3     4
B                 3     4
```

But if need compare per groups:

```
def f(x):
    print (x)
    m  = np.concatenate(( [True], x['Constraint_Flag'] != 0, [True] ))
    ss = np.flatnonzero(m[1:] != m[:-1]).reshape(-1,2)
    s, e = ss[(ss[:,1] - ss[:,0]).argmax()]
    pos = x.columns.get_loc('Week')
    c = ['start','end']
    return pd.Series([x.iat[s, pos], x.iat[e-1, pos]], index=c)

   Week Product_Code  Constraint_Flag
0     1            A                1
2     2            A                0
4     3            A                0
6     4            A                0
8     5            A                1
   Week Product_Code  Constraint_Flag
1     1            B                0
3     2            B                1
5     3            B                0
7     4            B                0
9     5            B                0

df = df.groupby('Product_Code').apply(f)
print (df)
              start  end
Product_Code            
A                 2    4
B                 3    5
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.  I am currently getting an error on this line "s, e = ss[(ss[:,1] - ss[:,0]).argmax()]" saying - "ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence" - do you know why this may be?

Comment: @user1058210 yes, I think problem is no value `0`in some group.

Comment: One possible solution should be `if else` like `def f(x):
    print (x) if (x['Constraint_Flag'] == 0). any(): 
    m  = np.concatenate(( [True], x['Constraint_Flag'] != 0, [True] ))
    ss = np.flatnonzero(m[1:] != m[:-1]).reshape(-1,2)
    s, e = ss[(ss[:,1] - ss[:,0]).argmax()]
    pos = x.columns.get_loc('Week')
    c = ['start','end']
    return pd.Series([x.iat[s, pos], x.iat[e-1, pos]], index=c) else:  return pd.Series([np. nan, np. nan], index=c ) for return NaN for no 0 groups. 
`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!